# Radical problem: $\sqrt[6]{-1}=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{-1}}=\sqrt {-1}=i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers, radicals

I'm stuck in a very simple problem . But, I could not find an answer in the books. That's why I want to ask MSE.

> Why is not this correct (according to Wolfram Alpha) ?
>
> $\sqrt[6]{-1}=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{-1}}=\sqrt {-1}=i$
>
> $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$, Because, $(-1)^3=-1.$

*Where is the mistake?*

Comment: The power rules do not hold in general if non-real numbers are involved. But here, we do not even have a problem because $i^2=-1$ which fits to the fact that the square of the sixth-root is the third root.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity

Comment: There are 6 roots to $z^6 = - 1$ one of which is $i$ but only one is the "principle root" that wolfram-alpha returns.

Comment: Is it undefined $\sqrt[3]{-a}$ ?, $a>0$

Answer (score 2):

It's "correct" in the sense that $i^6=(-1)^3=-1$, but many solutions are missed. The solutions of $z^3=-1$ are $-e^{2\pi ik/3}$ with $k\in\{0,\,1,\,2\}$, while those of $z^6=-1$ are $ie^{\pi ik/3}$ with $k\in\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\,4,\,5\}$.

Comment: $k=0$, $(-e)^0=1$, $1^3=-1?$.. can you explain me?plz

Comment: @Newuser In each case the solution you obtained is the $k=0$ one, but each of the other listed values of $k$ works as well. Note that $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$.

Comment: I think I need a teacher. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to understand. Thanks for the answer. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$-1$ has six different sixth roots. You listed one of them; there are still five more.

To write $\sqrt[6]{-1}$ as if it is a well-defined notation requires a convention to decide which of the sixth roots to give. The [usual convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Exponentiation&oldid=820814284#Powers_of_complex_numbers) is not the one you listed.

Note, incidentally, that the usual convention also has $\sqrt[3]{-1} \neq -1$. When moving away from the real numbers to the more general setting of the complex numbers, we no longer use the convention based on the weird property of real numbers that every real number has a unique cube root.

Comment: İs it undefined? $\sqrt[3]{-a}$